# Where to put my .txt files for PHP to read them in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I am creating a small application that is going to read .txt files and put each row of text in the database. I am not sure where to put those .txt files so that it's in accordance with Laravel standards. Should I put those files in the /public/ directory and access them from a controller via `public_path()` helper function?

The documentation seems to omit that information. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: i think public directory will better

Comment: It's really a preference I usually put those things in `storage/app`. And call it like `base_path('storage/app')`

Comment: @Daan so there is no universal rule about this?

Comment: No I don't think so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the local driver, note that all file operations are relative to the root directory defined in your configuration file. By default, this value is set to the ***`storage/app`*** directory. Therefore, the following method would store a file in `storage/app/file.txt`

[Laravel Configuration](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/filesystem#configuration)

Comment: @Pe-Ter happy to help :)

Comment: I did, I had to wait a few minutes before I was able to accept the answer. Stack overflow prevents from premature answer acceptance.

Comment: @Pe-Ter its ok. Thanks any way